# GStreamer - concatenate multiple mp4

Tags: c++, c, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I have multiple mp4 files with the following filename patterns `[0-9]{4}.mp4` and my goal is to arbitrarily concatenate 2 or more of them which have consecutive filenames (e.g. `0056.mp4`, `0057.mp4`, `0058.mp4`)

I already found the following pipeline but I cannot find a way to specify a proper location pattern for my use case.

```
gst-launch-1.0 splitmuxsrc location='0*.mp4' ! h264parse ! qtmux ! filesink location=concat.mp4
```

Comment: My gut feeling tells me that here is at least a `qtdemux` missing.

Comment: Or maybe it does the demux already? I actually never came across this particular element.

Comment: Probably yes, the pipeline I provided works perfectly, the only problem is that the glob pattern does not work well when I want to specify multiple files.

Comment: Ah, what exactlz means "does not work"? the pipeleine does not work? Wrong order? No files found at all?

Comment: It expects a glob pattern and I cannot find a way to specify what I described in my question (if that's even possible with this element), so "no files found" at all.

Comment: So it uses `gst_split_util_find_files` from `gstsplitutils.c`. Perhaps increasing the verbose level when running gives some insight. Perhaps they need to have a base path - e.g. try to prefix the pattern with `./`.

Comment: Try using the pattern: "%04d.mp4" instead of *. 

Try setting GST_DEBUG=splitmuxsrc:6 to see debug logs about what the element is doing.